# Python json to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to convert a json data set file into csv.  I am really new to python, and have been looking on the forums and cannot seem to resolve my issues.  I have attached the json data url link in below along with my code.  Thanks in advance!

https://data.ny.gov/api/views/nqur-w4p7/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD

```
import json
import csv

    inputFile = ("rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD", "r")
    data = json.load(inputFile)

    with open("Data.csv","wb") as csvfile:
      csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile,delimiter=",", fieldnames=["data", "new_york_state_average_gal", "albany_average_gal", "binghamton_average_gal", "bu\
    ffalo_average_gal", "nassau_average_gal", "new_york_city_average_gal", "rochester_average_gal", "utica_average_gal"])
      csv_writer.writerheader()
      csv_writer.writerows(data)
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
  File "ChangeDataType.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = json.load(inputFile)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 265, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: You're missing the word `open`...

Comment: Change it to `data = json.load(open(inputFile))`

Comment: @DustinSmith that should be a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error happens because you made a tuple:

```
inputFile = ("rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD", "r")
```

And you're trying to use `json.load` in that tuple. Since `json.load` works only on files, you need to call the `open` function:

```
inputFile = open("rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD", "r")
```

The `"r"` part indicates you're opening the file for reading.