# Python 3 JSON writing to CSV Error

Tags: python, json, export-to-csv

I am trying to write out a csv file from data in JSON format.  I can get the fieldnames to write to the csv file but not the item value I need.  This is my first time coding in python so any help would be appreciated.  The json file can be found below for reference:

https://data.ny.gov/api/views/nqur-w4p7/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ChangeDataType.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = json.dumps(inputFile)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 230, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 192, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 250, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 173, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'> is not JSON serializable
```

Here is my code:

```
import json
import csv

inputFile = open("rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD", "r")
data = json.dumps(inputFile)

with open("Data.csv","w") as csvfile:

    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, extrasaction='ignore', fieldnames=["date", "new_york_state_average_gal", "albany_average_gal", "binghamton_average_gal",\
 "buffalo_average_gal", "nassau_average_gal", "new_york_city_average_gal", "rochester_average_gal", "syracuse_average_gal","utica_average_gal"])

    writer.writeheader()

    for row in data:
        writer.writerow([row["date"], row["new_york_state_average_gal"], row["albany_average_gal"], row["binghamton_average_gal"],\
                         row["buffalo_average_gal"], row["nassau_average_gal"], row["new_york_city_average_gal"], row["rochester_average_gal"], row["syracuse\
_average_gal"],row["utica_average_gal"]])
```

Comment: `dumps` is for exporting json. You're trying to import it - use `loads`.

Comment: @Shadow That is what I originally had it as, but it was returning JSON must be string not 'TextI0Wrapper'

Comment: `load` without the s, the `s` is when you are loading from a string instead of a file.

Comment: Cause you're passing in the file pointer rather than the contents of the file. Try `json.load` if you're going to do it that way.

Comment: Why does your file end with `?accessType=DOWNLOAD`?

Comment: Okay thank you.  I my indices are still not integer, why would that be? and I used wget command and that is the format it was in.

Comment: Here is the link to it: https://data.ny.gov/api/views/nqur-w4p7/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD

Comment: Your previous question told you to use load function by the way ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579348/python-json-to-csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you're still having problems even opening the file. 
[Python json to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579348/python-json-to-csv)

You were told to use `json.load`

`dumps` takes an object to a string. You want to read JSON *to a dictionary*.

You therefore need to `load` the JSON file, and you can open two files  at once

```
with open("Data.csv","w") as csvfile, open("rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD") as inputfile:
    data = json.load(inputfile)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile,...
```

Also, for example, considering the JSON data looks like `"fieldName" : "syracuse_average_gal"`, and that is the only occurrence of the Syracuse average value, `row["syracuse_average_gal"]` is not correct.

Carefully inspect your JSON and figure out to parse it from the very top bracket

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read a JSON file you should use `json.load` instead of `json.dumps`:

```
data = json.load(inputFile)
```